# How to setup the dev environment to integrate K2 and Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, k2

I am looking for setting up the dev enviroment for Sharepoint 2010 ant  K2 and making it to a VHD . Can anyone please share the software and Hardware requirements for setup ?

Answer (score 1):

K2 supplies VHDs for demo and training purposes if you ask nicely.

If you're working with a K2 sales representative, already own the software, or are an active partner, you may be able to get a copy of K2 blackpearl installed and configured alongside SharePoint 2007 or 2010.

Here's the support line as one possible point of entry unless you've got other contact information:
http://help.k2.com/en/GlobalContacts.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for the ultimate development environment guide.

This is what I have found so far...
http://sharepoint2010blog.blogspot.com/2010/01/installing-sharepoint-2010-whole-9.html
http://www.pptspaces.com/sharepointreporterblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=28
http://www.pptspaces.com/sharepointreporterblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=7
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/Install_SharePoint_on_VPC.aspx
http://www.windowsreference.com/dns/step-by-step-guide-for-windows-server-2003-domain-controller-and-dns-server-setup/
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684791.aspx

If anyone finds more please add to this list :)